# Как получить московское время сейчас?

Tags: python, время

Необходимо в Python программе получить московское время сейчас. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно без сторонних модулей

```
import datetime

offset = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=3))

print(datetime.datetime.now(offset))
```

```
2019-03-27 21:05:52.023288+03:00
```

Comment: И тут внезапно госдума опять решит перевести часы

Comment: Помнится на пол года отключал автоматический часовой пояс в системе, потому что не обновляли) так что неизвестно что проще актуализировать - свое приложение или таймзону

Comment: Я когда-то написал подобный код в своих программах, а потом в октябре 2014-го ночью очень сильно страдал

Comment: «что проще актуализировать» — очевидно, таймзону, потому что pytz обновляется регулярно и своевременно

Answer (score 8):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz     #   pip install pytz

moscow_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))
print(moscow_time)
```

---

```
2019-03-27 20:51:26.031936+03:00
```

Comment: А это не привязано к часовому поясу компьютера? Т.е. если у меня стоит неправильный часовой пояс, то и результат неправильный получится?

Comment: @Эникейщик, нет, не привязано. У меня на компе часовой пояс - `Europe/Berlin` и московское время показывается правильно

Comment: @MaxU у pytz жесткая привязка к локальному времени компьютера