# Как получить дату которая не зависит от даты указанной в системе

Tags: python, дата, datetime

`datetime.now()` выводит дату которая установлено в системе. Как можно узнать дату, которая не зависит от настроек системы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962245/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81

Comment: Какие именно настройки системы вы имеете в виду - часовой пояс или и сами настройки даты-времени тоже? Расшифруйте ваш вопрос, сейчас его можно понимать по-разному.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В основном, все `Python` библиотеки связанные с датой `(datetime, pytz, ...)` используют для своей работы ту информацию, которая выставлена в ОС, поэтому с помощью них получить данные, которые никак не связаны с настройками системы - не получится.

Но есть выход, можно сделать запрос на какой-либо `ntp` сервер (сервер точного времени), самый популярный - `ntp.org`, и дополнительно нужно обладать списком временных зон (через модуль, например), чтобы получить необходимые данные из ответа сервера.

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Для начала, через пакетный менеджер `pip` устанавливаем требуемые модули, содержащие информацию о всех временных зонах, и также интерфейс `ntp`-клиента для работы с сервером:

> `$ pip install zoneinfo, tzdata, ntplib`

2. Отправляем запрос на сервер и получаем нужную информацию из ответа согласно требуемой временной зоне.

Код:

```
import datetime
import ntplib
import zoneinfo

tz_info = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("Europe/Moscow")

ntp_server = 'pool.ntp.org'
client = ntplib.NTPClient()

response = client.request(ntp_server)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, tz=tz_info)

print(dt)
```

Вывод:

```
2023-01-08 11:51:11.134537+03:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.utcnow())
```

`UTC` ("Всемирное координированное время") - дата и время без учёта часового пояса системы (но зависящее от выставленных даны и времени в системе)

Comment: У меня при смене даты на компьютере вывод отличается.
Не уверен, что таким простым образом можно, даже `pytz` оказалась тоже с привязкой к времени системы

Comment: @Павел Не понял тезиса. Что именно отличается?

Comment: ну вопрос ведь именно в том, чтобы получить дату, которая не зависит от настроек системы. Я запустил ваш код - получил одну дату, затем поменял время в системе, запустил повторно, и получил новую дату, которая отличается от первоначально полученной

Comment: @Павел А, понятно. Тут надо уточнять у автора вопроса - что же он всё-таки хотел получить. Ваш вариант с `ntp` выглядит подходящим, но никогда нет уверенности в том, что именно имел в виду автор вопроса.